# exceptionPreprocess Unknown crash in app

Tags: ios

Hi My app is crashing randomly

Please help to find the solution
Here I am sending you the crash report.

```
0   
CoreFoundation 0x24629fef __exceptionPreprocess + 127

1   
libobjc.A.dylib 0x32f6dc8b objc_exception_throw + 36

2   
CoreFoundation 0x2462f409 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186

3   
CoreFoundation 0x2462d327 ___forwarding___ + 712

4   
CoreFoundation 0x2455ce78 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 22

5   
UIKit 0x27cd8777 -[UIViewAnimationState actionForLayer:forKey:forView:] + 68

6   
UIKit 0x27ca1489 +[UIView(Animation) _defaultUIViewActionForLayer:forKey:] + 86

7   
UIKit 0x27ca109d -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) actionForLayer:forKey:] + 114

8   
QuartzCore 0x276b7487 -[CALayer actionForKey:] + 144
9   
QuartzCore 0x276ad9f9 _ZL12actionForKeyP7CALayerPN2CA11TransactionEP8NSString + 54

10  
QuartzCore 0x276ad8df _ZN2CA5Layer12begin_changeEPNS_11TransactionEjRP11objc_object + 128

11  
QuartzCore 0x276b0b5b _ZN2CA5Layer6setterEj12_CAValueTypePKv + 176

12  
QuartzCore 0x276b73f1 -[CALayer setOpacity:] + 34

13  
UIKit 0x27ca0b0b -[UIView(Rendering) setAlpha:] + 112

14  
MediaPlayer 0x25ef4cf5 -[MPVolumeSlider _layoutForAvailableRoutes] + 1302

15  
MediaPlayer 0x25f01db3 __59-[MPAVRoutingController _scheduleSendDelegateRoutesChanged]_block_invoke + 120

16  
libdispatch.dylib 0x334fe2e3 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8

17  
libdispatch.dylib 0x334fe2cf _dispatch_client_callout + 20

18  
libdispatch.dylib 0x33501d2f _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1328

19  
CoreFoundation 0x245ef609 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 6

20  
CoreFoundation 0x245edd09 __CFRunLoopRun + 1510

21  
CoreFoundation 0x2453a201 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 474

22  
CoreFoundation 0x2453a013 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104

23  
GraphicsServices 0x2c00b201 GSEventRunModal + 134

24  
UIKit 0x27d06a09 UIApplicationMain + 1438

25  
RepublicHybridQA copy 0x000addbb main (main.m:17)

26  
libdyld.dylib 0x3351faaf start + 0
```

Comment: Did you add an exception breakpoint and try to figure out the exact line

Comment: I don't know where the crash is in my app. This crash is happened randomly in my production app  (app from app store) to one of the users. I can't test it by putting exception break points.

Comment: please read about exception breakpoint somewhere and try to replicate the crsah.

Comment: Actual issue is, I unable reproduce the crash from my XCODE